# rails heroku db:seed not going through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, model

I recently destroyed my `Player` model, and generated a `User` model, with pretty much the same fields except the User one has `username:string, email:string, password:digest`.

I also have a Blog model which is in a one-to-many relationship with the User model (previously with the Player model).

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :blogs, dependent: :destroy
end

class Blog < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Problem is, on Heroku console, the Blog model still has player_id field from before.

```
Blog(id: integer, player_id: integer, content: text, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
```

I can run `heroku run rails db:migrate`, but when I try to run `heroku run rails db:seed`, it gives me this error.

```
ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute `user_id`
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scaffold generators will not rebuild old DB tables for you, just make new ones. You need to create a migration that renames the `player_id` column.

On the console run this command:

```
rails g migration RenamePlayerIdOnBlogs
```

Then within the file it generates, add the following code:

```
class RenamePlayerIdOnBlogs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    rename_column :blogs, :player_id, :user_id
  end
end
```

Then run `rake db:migrate` and you should be OK.

Comment: Do I run this on my local server and then push to heroku or heroku run it?

Comment: because on my local console the Blog model shows the correct field (user_id)

Comment: The migration will alter the database. Commit this using git, push to Heroku, the run `heroku run rake db:migrate`

Comment: You didn't show what migrations you already have. Did you do `rake db:rollback` locally? Or perhaps dropped the DB and started again?

Comment: so i ran the migration and got this error "No such column: blogs.player_id"

Comment: I think I did drop the DB and started again

Comment: After I destroyed the Player model I deleted all the relevant migration files because it looked cluttered...which im sensing might have been a terrible idea

Comment: it worked!!! i generated the migration file and then heroku ran it and it worked! thank you Matt

Comment: Yeah, keep the migrations! Only delete if they're old and you know it all works. If you have no important data on Heroku, drop the DB there and recreate it: `heroku run rake db:drop db:create db:schema:load`. Otherwise you'll need to make your local db look like the one on heroku and go from there. Easiest if you download a backup and load that locally.

Comment: Awesome! To get your local schema.rb in sync with Heroku, it would be best to load the dump anyway and then run `rake db:migrate` locally. Should work cleanly in future then.